# Use of two if statements in a row, which statement actually is being used?

Tags: python

I'm trying to reproduce some code and make minor changes, but am getting tripped up by something seemingly simple. It gives two if statements in a row. The first statement is false and the second statement is true. An example is straightforward

```
y = 2
if 2 > 1 and 2 > 3:
    if 2 > 0:
        print (y)
```

This gives me nothing, which makes me think the code only reads the first if statement, which is false.

Now:

```
if 2 > 1 and 3 > 2:
    if 2 > 100:
        print (y)
```

also gives me nothing, even though the first statement is true, making me wonder if the code is reading the second statement?

```
if 2 > 1 and 3 > 2:
    if 2 > 0:
        print (y)
```

This prints `y`, but does it do so because it's reading the first statement, second statement, or both (like if and)?

Comment: The second `if` will be executed only if the first one is `True`, which is pretty obvious as it is exactly what `if` does - executing the next statement only if the condition is true..

Comment: Nothing inside the first `if` statement is executed when the condition is false. So it never executes the second `if` statement, and it doesn't matter whether its condition is true or false.

Comment: In your second code block, the first condition is true, but the second one is false, so it doesn't execute the body of the second `if`. But it's certainly reading the second `if`.

Comment: expanding on the above comments, logical expressions joined by `and` will be executed in order until one returns `false`, while statements joined by `or` are executed until the first `true` is found.

Comment: chaining `if` statements this way is equivalent to an `and`: `if 2 > 1 and 3 > 2 and 2 > 100:`

Comment: In your first case, what you've effectively done is write `if 2 > 1 and 2 > 3 and 2 > 0: print(y)`

Comment: @G.Anderson In fact it is effectively as if you write nothing :)

Comment: Thanks guys. I will probably just do without if statements. The first statement will always be false and the second statement needs to execute. I was just unsure

Comment: It sounds like you want the equivalent of `if (2 > 1 and 3 > 2) or 2 > 0:`. But if you know you want the code to execute under all conditions, then as you say there's no real point to using an 'if'.

Comment: "do without if statements"? These are the most basic control structures in coding. It's practically impossible to do anything useful without them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first code the second **if** statement will only be evaluated if the first **if** statement is true, therefore, since the first **if** statement is false, the second **if** statement will not be examined.

In the second code, both **if** statements are evaluated. However, the print statement is only executed if the second **if** statement is also true. Since the second **if** statement is false, the print statement is not executed

In the third code, both **if** statements are true, so every statement within the **if** block is executed.

To summarize, the code follows a top-down approach, where the statements are executed in the order in which they appear. If the condition of the first **if** statement is false, the code will skip the code block associated with that **if** statement and move on to the next statement.